# Is it possible to compile GLib (and then compile Autotrace) with Emscripten?

Tags: glib, emscripten, ninja, meson-build

Compiling with [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/) seems really easy with typical `configure`, `make` and `make install` workflows.

I would like to compile [Autotrace](https://github.com/autotrace/autotrace) (which uses this workflow), but it requires [GLib](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib).

In the Emscripten doc, it is mentioned that in such case GLib must be compiled with Emscripten. However GLib uses `meson` and `ninja` as compile tools.

Is it possible to compile GLib with Emscripten? (and will it be enough to get Autotrace working in a browser?)

Answer (score 2):

Meson supports cross-compiling, so you can treat Emscripten as a cross compiler by writing a 'cross file':

**emscripten.txt**

```
[binaries]
c = '/opt/emsdk-portable/emscripten/1.38.8/emcc'
cpp = '/opt/emsdk-portable/emscripten/1.38.8/em++'
ar = '/opt/emsdk-portable/emscripten/1.38.8/emar'
#exe_wrapper = 'node'

[properties]
root = '/opt/emsdk-portable/emscripten/1.38.8/system'
c_args = ['-s', 'WASM=1', '-O2']
c_link_args = ['-s', 'WASM=1','-O2']
cpp_args = ['-s', 'WASM=1','-O2']
cpp_link_args = ['-s', 'WASM=1','-O2']
shared_lib_suffix = 'js'
static_lib_suffix = 'js'
shared_module_suffix = 'js'
exe_suffix = 'js'

[host_machine]
system = 'emscripten'
cpu_family = 'x86'
cpu = 'i686'
endian = 'little'
```

(This was taken from https://github.com/prozum/meson-samples/blob/master/emscripten.txt)

Replace the paths with the paths to your Emscripten tools. Then invoke meson with `meson --cross-file=emscripten.txt`.

Comment: Thanks! But I get this error: `ERROR: Problem encountered: Unsupported pair: system "emscripten", cpu family "x86"`. I tried with cpu_family = `x86_64`, `wasm32`, `wasm64` and nothing works.

Comment: You may need to look at the Meson documentation for the correct values to fill in the `[host]` section.

Comment: Is your meson version new enough?

Comment: maybe it's too recent, I just installed it, I have version 0.54.0